# How to add and Update at the same button click using Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i am creating a simple car retail system project in asp.net mvc.i had a problem is when the customer retuns a car avalablie column need to be changes yes.

**return**

```
id  carno   custid  date       elap fine
1   A0002   1   2019-11-29     11   1100
```

**car**

```
id  carno   make    model   Available
1   A0001   honda   viff    yes
2   A0002   Honda   uii     no
```

when the customer return the car. return table save the record success fully. i don't how to update to car table Available no change  need to be yes.

**i tried the code. return car save**

```
 public ActionResult Save(returncar recar)
 {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
           db.returncars.Add(recar);
           db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");

      }

      return View(recar);
 }
```

**Form Design**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "return", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "popupForm" }))
        {
            <div>
                <h4> Registation</h4>
            </div>


            <div class="card-action">
                <label class="form-label">Car ID</label>
                  <input type="text" id="carno" name="carno" class="form-control" placeholder="carno" required />
            </div>



            <div class="card-action">

                <label class="form-label">Customer ID</label>

                <input type="text" id="custid" name="custid" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer ID" required />

            </div>



            <div class="card-action">

                <label class="form-label">Date</label>

                <input type="text" id="date" name="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" required />

            </div>


             <div class="card-action">

                <label class="form-label">Days Elapsed</label>

                 <input type="text" id="elap" name="elap" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" required />

            </div>


             <div class="card-action">

                <label class="form-label">Fine</label>

                 <input type="text" id="fine" name="fine" class="form-control" placeholder="Fine" required />

            </div>


            <div class="card">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>

        }
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can check for if the car exists in the db and then update the existing object like db.returncars.Where(x=>x.id == recar.id).FirstOrDefault(). This will give you the car object if it exists and then you can update the values

Comment: yes it there carregs table name.             db.carregs.Where(x => x.id == recar.id).FirstOrDefault(); this how have to write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, it seems that you want to update Car `Available` attribute to `true` when the Car returns.

So simple you can find the Car using `carno` and if exists update its status. Here is how you can do this.

```
public ActionResult Save(returncar recar)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.returncars.Add(recar);
            //I realized that the carno is unique
            var car= db.cars.SingleOrDefault(e => e.carno == recar.carno);
            if(car == null)
            return HttpNotFound("CarNo is not valid");

            car.Available = true;
            db.Entry(car).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }

      return View(recar);
    }
```

So this will update your Car `Available` attribute to true when a `Car` will be returned.

Comment: car.Available = true;  sir line error  convert to bool to string

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: @Javafiver I've updated `car.Available = true;` I was assuming it a string.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
public class Return
{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int carno {get; set;}

   public string carno {get; set;}   
   // Other code goes here.
}

public class car
{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string carno {get; set;}
   public string Available {get; set;}
   // Other code goes here.
}
```

and Modify your Controller Action Save method:

```
var car = db.cars.FirstOrDefault(c => c.carno == recar.carno);

if (car != null) {
    db.returncars.Add(recar);
    car.Available = "yes";
    ((DbEntryEntity)car).State = EntityState.Modified;  
    db.SaveChanges();
}
else {
  // Handle it
}
```